# What is difference between Docker and Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, macos, docker-desktop

I am using a mac and apparently installing `Docker Desktop` is mandatory to use Docker in macOS. Why Docker Desktop is required in Mac and Windows OS, and not in Linux? What purpose Docker Desktop serves? I have tried googling it but can't find appropriate answers.

Comment: Similar, though not quite a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464724/whats-the-difference-between-docker-for-windows-and-docker-on-windows/40320748

Comment: I hope someone can provide a more detailed answer to this, but generally speaking, Docker requires a Linux host. Docker Desktop provides some sort of Linux virtual machine in which Docker can run. That isn't required on a Linux system, because it is already Linux :)

Comment: @jakub I also thought that might be the case but couldn't find it documented anywhere. So is Docker only supposed to run on Linux? And if we wish to run it on mac/windows we'll need to run it on Linux VM? Is that the case?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

docker desktop for both mac and windows is using a Linux virtual machine behind the scenes for running regular docker daemon.

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/)
That state docker for windows is using WSL2 which is running a VM.
[Here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#general) there is a mention of backing up docker VM on docker for mac.

> Docker Desktop handles the setup and teardown of lightweight VMs on both Windows and macOS, using Hyper-V on Windows desktops and Hyperkit on macOS.

[From docker blog](https://www.docker.com/blog/get-to-know-docker-desktop/) .

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I updated my answer with link that mentioned the VM not directly, I'm sure you can find more about this with a little search. 
Also on windows you can just list WSL in powershell and there is WSL running for docker.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, this links mentions running VM in the background.

Comment: So the 64,000 dollar question (literally, if you have a big enough team) is: if you install docker desktop but only use docker _engine_ via the CLI, are you using docker desktop? And  also/if so, can you get docker _engine_ running on a mac on a VM without docker desktop?

Comment: @OliverWilliams: "if you install docker desktop but only use docker engine via the CLI, are you using docker desktop?" --> yes, because you would have not got Docker Engine without Docker Desktop. Of course, you can install Docker Engine standalone as well.

Comment: @OliverWilliams: "can you get docker engine running on a mac on a VM without docker desktop?" --> yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 10):

**Docker:** It is the main service which runs containers, this runs on linux kernel (linux VM on Mac and Windows), docker is open source and free to use. Alternatives to docker are Podman.

**Docker Desktop:** It is the commercial GUI tool, which helps us to run, list, edit etc. our container configs. This is free to use (but at some extent like big orgs need to buy licenses to use it for commercial developments).

Answer (score 0):

**Docker Desktop is a kind of graphical overlay that facilitates the management** of Docker-related tasks.

This is a separate program (with additional license restrictions), **but it's not required if you want to use Docker and its components via the CLI** (available for free for commercial use).

On macOS you can install Docker using `brew`:

```
brew install docker
```

If you want to use the *macOS Keychain* as the credential store for remote container repos instead of Docker Desktop, also install `docker-credential-helper`:

```
brew install docker-credential-helper
```

More:

- [Overview of Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/)
- [How to use Docker without Docker Desktop on MacOS](https://dev.to/elliotalexander/how-to-use-docker-without-docker-desktop-on-macos-217m)